# Pi as HF ham band transmitter and FM repeater

Tags: gpio, pifm

If the pi is able to transmit fm signals from 1 to 250mhz wiht pifm and it has been used as an HF qrp transmitter why hasnt it been further developed as an HF transmitter with a small cheap amplifier? Also if it does transmit in the 2meter ham band why hasnt anyone built an FM repeater? Can the pi receive in the same frequencies it transmits?

Comment: I'm not sure the Pi can do those things.  The doubtful legality in some jurisdictions may be an additional problem.

Comment: Even if you could get allowable modulation formats (which are quite different from wideband FM), trivially digitally generated signals are generally not spectrally clean enough to be permissibly amplified.  Digital synthesis is of course possible, but typically requires purposeful design (or at least informed selection) of the generating components and cleanup filtering afterwards - in some ways it is harder to build a clean digital transmitter than it is a clean digital receiver.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know R_PI can only generate FM, by varying the frequency of an oscillator/timer.

This is no good for HF which uses much narrower bandwidths. You need to generate SSB which requires a lot of maths. Look up Software Defined Radios.

You could get software to generate what are called In-phase and Quadrature audio signals on the R_PI, several SDR programs do this. But you will then need some hardware to mix the IQ signal up to the HF frequency you want. Several HW designs are about on the wen for this.

A friend of mine has run Quisk SDR program on the R_PI as a receiver using a simple SDR from github.com/M6KWH.

Answer (score 1):

If you properly filter the Pi's output before amplification and the antenna, and use a cheap RTL-SDR USB dongle for reception, you can use a Pi as a transceiver.  See: http://www.rtl-sdr.com/building-a-ham-tranceiver-with-an-rtl-sdr-raspberry-pi-and-rpitx/ for one example project.